# Correctly deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18003060
is being presented as a review audit.

The system declares that the reviewer should act to delete it because it is spam or offensive etc.

I see nothing offensive in the text.

> Personally, it looks like an all right candidate for logistic regression, but the fact that it looks 1-dimensional with overlapping may make it hard to separate along those parts. I’m mainly here to answer the second part of your question which can be generalized to pretty much any other classifier within scikit-learn.
>
> I recommend looking at the scikit-learn section on SGDClassifier since it has a simple example right below the attribute list, but replace the SGDClassifier part with the LogisticRegression class instead.

Perhaps the links are to a commercial or ad supported site:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Nope that's not it:

```
scikit-learn
Machine Learning in Python

Simple and efficient tools for data mining and data analysis
Accessible to everybody, and reusable in various contexts
Built on NumPy, SciPy, and matplotlib
Open source, commercially usable - BSD license

Fork us on GitHub
```

Using this is an audit test and telling people that the available evidence suggests it should be deleted seems a difficult standard to set to me.

Unless there is something I am unaware of it seems to me it is possible to argue the answer might have been deleted in error.

**Questions**

What about this post made it something that should be deleted?

What should a reviewer asked to review this audit question be looking for to decide it should be deleted?

**Edit**

I did more reading and I can see an argument that the original question  might have been better posted on the stats stackexchange site as opposed to SO. That makes some sense. Might that be the rationale that the answer should be deleted maybe?

I hope all this reads as a search for understanding of how to be a better reviewer (because that's how I intend it) and not snark.

Comment: I think the moderator that handled the post missed the spam flag on it, I'll clear the flag.

Comment: You know there’s something wrong when the audit tells you that the post should be deleted, whereas [the post is not deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47267778/2711488). That would be quiet inconsistent.

Comment: @Holger Note that it's currently undeleted because Martijn undeleted it - see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47267778/revisions

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue

Comment: @Mark Amery: so I got confused by Martijn’s comment saying “*I think the moderator that handled the post missed the spam flag on it*”, which doesn’t read like “*I think the moderator that handled the post should not have deleted it*”, I mean, if that moderator missed the spam flag on it, why did he delete the post?

Comment: Looks to me like the answer would be better placed in a comment, but is certainly not SPAM.